# Codeigniter/.htaccess exception to allow push script from bitbucket

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I followed [this](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/) tutorial to automate my deployments from `bitbucket` but unfortunately it seems I have run into some problems. My web application is using `Codeigniter` and the built in MVC routing is not allowing the php script to be called. I'm not sure how I would allow an exception to call the file.

In particular, I want to allow a request such as `http://mydomain/deploy/script.php` through the CI routing scheme. I'm not sure if this can be done through `routes.php`, but if so that would be preferred rather than working with `.htaccess` files because I am still very noobish when it comes to apache. Many thanks, I have been stuck on this for some time!

Edit:

Current .htaccess in webroot:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is `script.php` in root directory next to `index.php`?

Comment: Script.php is inside deploy which is inside the root Web directory. Index.php is also in root

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` code in edited question.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the htaccess file

Comment: Why are you putting your deploy trigger script in your web directory?  This sounds like a REALLY BAD idea.  That is unless you want any random person in the world to be able to deploy your site.

Comment: What would you suggest?